# Laravel 5.3: Weird alert login and sign up message

Tags: laravel, authentication

In my Laravel 5.3 project, when user input incorrect email or password into login form, it display message "auth.failed". For registration, it dispays "validation.unique" or "validation.confirmed" as in the picture.

[image]

I don't know what I have done wrong. Please kindly advise.
thanks, Devith

Answer (score 0):

Problem is probably in your view file and you are not printing out $error array correctly. But without any code in your post it's hard to help :) https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors

Comment: In my view, I did follow this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors but it shows such message